# Problem executing the Python code for Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written this code and it executes without any error. However, it does not give any output when I call the function.

```
import re
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from dateutil.parser import parse
from newspaper import Article


class NewspaperScraper:
    def __init__ (self, newspaper, searchTerm, dateStart, dateEnd):
        self.newspaper = newspaper
        self.searchTerm = searchTerm
        self.dateStart = parse(dateStart)
        self.dateEnd = parse(dateEnd)
        self.links = []

    def get_newspaper_name (self):
        return self.newspaper

    def get_pages (self):
        print ('Unimplemented for ' + self.newspaper + ' scraper')
        return

    def check_dates (self, date):
        page_date = parse(date)
        if page_date >= self.dateStart and page_date <= self.dateEnd:
            return True
        return False

    def newspaper_parser (self, sleep_time=0):
        print ('running newspaper_parser()...')

        results = []
        count = 0

        for l in self.links:
            article = Article(url=l)
            try:
                article.build()
            except:
                time.sleep(60)
                continue

            data = {
                'title': article.title,
                'date_published': article.publish_date,
                'news_outlet': self.newspaper,
                'authors': article.authors,
                'feature_img': article.top_image,
                'article_link': article.canonical_link,
                'keywords': article.keywords,
                'movies': article.movies,
                'summary': article.summary,
                'text': article.text,
                'html': article.html
            }

            print (data['title'])
            print (data['text'])
            print
            print
            results.append(data)

            count += 1
            print (count)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        return results

    def write_to_csv (self, data, file_name):
        print ('writing to CSV...')

        keys = data[0].keys()
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as output_file:
            dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
            dict_writer.writeheader()
            dict_writer.writerows(data)

    def write_to_mongo (self, data, collection):
        print ('writing to mongoDB...')
        count = 0

        for d in data:
            collection.insert(d)
            count += 1
            print (count)
```

Here I have a specific code for Washington Post articles.

```
class WashPostScraper(NewspaperScraper):
    def get_pages (self, sleep_time=3):
        print ('running get_pages()...')

        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe')

        links = []
        stop = False
        index = 0

        while not stop:
            browser.get('https://www.washingtonpost.com/newssearch/'
                        + '?utm_term=.94befa345ad6&query='
                        + self.searchTerm
                        + '&sort=Date&datefilter=12%20Months&contenttype=Article'
                        + '&spellcheck&startat=' + str(index) + '#top')

            soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
            if not soup.find_all('div', class_="pb-feed-item"):
                stop = True
                continue

            for result in soup.find_all('div', class_="pb-feed-item"):
                if self.check_dates(result.find('span', class_='pb-timestamp').get_text()):
                    link = result.find('a', class_="ng-binding")
                    ltext = link.get('href')

                    if ltext not in links:
                        print(ltext)
                        links.append(ltext)

                else:
                    stop = True
                    break

            index += 20
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        browser.close()
        self.links = links
        return links
```

Here, I call the functions

```
neighbor = WashPostScraper('Washington Post', "economy", '5/1/1992', '7/23/2020')
b = neighbor.get_pages()
c = neighbor.newspaper_parser(b)
```

The code executes properly. But when called, I get an empty output. Am I calling it incorrectly?
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The bare `elif` in `initialize_scraper` is a syntax error. Please [edit] to post working code, ideally reduced to a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee Made the edits. WIll make sure to post a minimal reproducible example from next time.

Comment: In the final row, `args[1]` is `'economy'`. How exactly are you running the script; it seems to run twice if you run it from the command line, but the first time the arguments will come from `sys.argv` (where it is correct but weird to ignore the zeroth element; usually you would call `function(sys.argv[1:])` instead) where we can't see your arguments, and the second time with the arguments out of whack. Perhaps it just runs without the expected arguments and thus doesn't actually do anything? But we still lack details.

Comment: You could easily add a debug `print` to `run_scraper` to print out the arguments it receives; if that doesn't print anything, my guess was correct.

Comment: @tripleee I figured that. I made some more changes and now I am directly calling the functions. It even gives a chrome pop up showing the search results for economy. It, however, again results in an empty list. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Where exactly do you get an empty result? In `b`, or in `c`, or somewhere else? Can you add more debugging information?

Comment: I made the changes. Sorry it is a big scraper so I mistakenly posted for other news article. It is now changed to Washington Post and you might need to change the executable path for Chrome extension. I get the empty result in c

Comment: And how many pages does the `neighbor` have in `b`, and how many articles is your code fetching?

Comment: Yeah the problem is that even b is an empty set. So, I am not sure where exactly am I going wrong. It does pop up the washington post web page with the search time of economy. So, the code is working but probably not storing?

Comment: If your scraping expressions are not freshly vetted with the newspaper's current templates, it's probably just that you are trying to extract elements which no longer exist, and the BS code needs to be updated; or maybe they updated search, and you need to tweak the URL you are passing in. Scraping like this is always brittle, and will break in obnoxious ways as soon as you look the other way.